# Methods being called numerous times

Tags: java, methods

I have methods x, y, z which are being called by methods balloonsNeeded and roomVolume.

The methods are being called twice and therefore running twice. I only need the methods xyz to run once but I need their variables twice. The issue can easily be fixed if I combined the methods but I have to keep all the mentioned methods separate.

i forgot to mention, i tried using arrays (probably incorrectly) and i was still having the same issue.

```java
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        //X(); \\testing
        //Y(); \\testing
        //Z(); \\testing
        //roomVolume(); \\testing
        //balloonVolume(); \\testing
        balloonsNeeded();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    //Finding axis X
    public static double X() {
        String x;
        double xDouble;

        //takes the users input
        System.out.println("What is the rooms width in cm?");
        x = scanner.nextLine();

        //insures the user hasnt entered any letters
        if (x.matches(".*[a-zA-Z.*]")) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is invalid, please enter a value using only [0-9]");
            return X();
        } else {
            //converts the users input into a double value
            xDouble = Double.parseDouble(x);
        }

        //insures the users input is larger than 0
        if (xDouble <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is 0 or smaller, please enter a value larger than 0");
            return X();
        } else {
            //returns the users input.
            return xDouble;
        }
    }


    //Finding axis Y
    static double Y() {
        String y;
        double yDouble;

        //takes the users input
        System.out.println("What is the rooms length in cm?");
        y = scanner.nextLine();

        //insures the user hasnt entered any letters
        if (y.matches(".*[a-zA-Z.*]")) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is invalid, please enter a value using only [0-9]");
            return Y();
        } else {
            //converts the users input into a double value
            yDouble = Double.parseDouble(y);
        }

        //insures the users input is larger than 0
        if (yDouble <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is 0 or smaller, please enter a value larger than 0");
            return Y();
        } else {
            //returns the users input.
            return yDouble;
        }
    }

    //Finding axis Z
    public static double Z() {
        String z;
        final double zDouble;

        //takes the users input
        System.out.println("What is the rooms height in cm?");
        z = scanner.nextLine();

        //insures the user hasnt entered any letters
        if (z.matches(".*[a-zA-Z.*]")) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is invalid, please enter a value using only [0-9]");
            return Z();
        } else {
            //converts the users input into a double value
            zDouble = Double.parseDouble(z);
        }

        //insures the users input is larger than 0
        if (zDouble <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is 0 or smaller, please enter a value larger than 0");
            return Z();
        } else {
            //returns the users input.
            return zDouble;
        }
    }


    //Calculating the rooms volume
    public static double roomVolume(){
        double rvDouble;
        final int million = 1000000;
        double rvRounded;

        //calls for the X, Y, Z methods to be run in order to obtain the variables
        double axisx = X();
        double axisy = Y();
        double axisz = Z();

        //calculates the rooms volume then divides it by 1,000,000 to convert it to m³
        rvDouble = (axisx*axisy*axisz)/million;

        //rounds the volume to 2 decimal points
        rvRounded = (double)Math.round(rvDouble*100)/100;

        //returns rooms volume
        return rvRounded;
    }

    //finding the balloons volume
    public static double balloonVolume() {
        String bv;
        double bvDouble;

        System.out.println("Whats your balloons volume?");
        bv = scanner.nextLine();

        //insures the user hasnt entered any letters
        if (bv.matches(".*[a-zA-Z.*]")) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is invalid, please enter a value using only [0-9]");
            return balloonVolume();
        } else {
            //converts the users input into a double value
            bvDouble = Double.parseDouble(bv);
        }

        //insures the users input is larger than 0
        if (bvDouble <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The value you entered is 0 or smaller, please enter a value larger than 0");
            return balloonVolume();
        } else {
            //returns balloon volume.
            return bvDouble;
        }
    }


    //finding the number of balloons needed to fill a room.
    public static int balloonsNeeded(){
        int bNeeded;
        double bNdouble;

        double rVol = roomVolume();
        double bVol = balloonVolume();
        double ax = X();
        double ay = Y();
        double az = Z();

        //calculates the number of balloons needed by dividing the rooms volume by the balloons volume.
        bNdouble = rVol/bVol;
        //converts the value from a double to an integer
        bNeeded = (int)bNdouble;

        //prints out the information to the user.
        System.out.println("The dimensions you entered are " + ax + "x" + ay + "x" + az + "cm." );
        System.out.println("This means your rooms volume is " + rVol + "m³");
        System.out.println("You will need " + bNeeded + " balloons to fill the room.");
        return bNeeded;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about calling x,y,z once before calling other methods and after pass the values to these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Like @KunLun mentioned in the comments,

```
public static double roomVolume(double axisx, double axisy, double axisz){
    double rvDouble;
    final int million = 1000000;
    double rvRounded;

    //calculates the rooms volume then divides it by 1,000,000 to convert it to m³
    rvDouble = (axisx*axisy*axisz)/million;

    //rounds the volume to 2 decimal points
    rvRounded = (double)Math.round(rvDouble*100)/100;

    //returns rooms volume
    return rvRounded;
}
```

And then you can simply call your method

```
public static int balloonsNeeded(){
    int bNeeded;
    double bNdouble;

    double ax = X();
    double ay = Y();
    double az = Z();
    double rVol = roomVolume(ax, ay, az);
    double bVol = balloonVolume();

    //calculates the number of balloons needed by dividing the rooms volume by the balloons volume.
    bNdouble = rVol/bVol;
    //converts the value from a double to an integer
    bNeeded = (int)bNdouble;

    //prints out the information to the user.
    System.out.println("The dimensions you entered are " + ax + "x" + ay + "x" + az + "cm." );
    System.out.println("This means your rooms volume is " + rVol + "m³");
    System.out.println("You will need " + bNeeded + " balloons to fill the room.");
    return bNeeded;
}
```

Comment: although the previous solution is more efficient, thank you for giving me this solution, this is what i needed as i needed to keep the methods X Y Z separate.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a lot of repeated code. Combine all that into one function. Then, get the input once, and pass as parameters where needed.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        balloonsNeeded();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static double getDouble(String prompt) {
        while (true) {
            //takes the users input
            System.out.println(prompt);
            String x = scanner.nextLine();
            try {
                double val = Double.parseDouble(x);
                if (val > 0) return val;
                System.out.println("The value you entered is 0 or smaller, please enter a value larger than 0");
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("The value you entered is invalid, please enter a value using only [0-9]");
            }
        }
    }

    //Calculating the rooms volume
    public static double roomVolume(double axisx, double axisy, double axisz) {
        double rvDouble;
        final int million = 1000000;
        double rvRounded;

        //calculates the rooms volume then divides it by 1,000,000 to convert it to m³
        rvDouble = (axisx*axisy*axisz)/million;

        //rounds the volume to 2 decimal points
        rvRounded = (double)Math.round(rvDouble*100)/100;

        //returns rooms volume
        return rvRounded;
    }

    //finding the number of balloons needed to fill a room.
    public static int balloonsNeeded(){
        double ax = getDouble("What is the rooms width in cm?");
        double ay = getDouble("What is the rooms length in cm?");
        double az = getDouble("What is the rooms height in cm?");

        double rVol = roomVolume(ax, ay, az);
        double bVol = getDouble("Whats your balloons volume?");

        //calculates the number of balloons needed by dividing the rooms volume by the balloons volume.
        double bNdouble = rVol/bVol;
        //converts the value from a double to an integer
        int bNeeded = (int)bNdouble;

        //prints out the information to the user.
        System.out.println("The dimensions you entered are " + ax + "x" + ay + "x" + az + "cm." );
        System.out.println("This means your rooms volume is " + rVol + "m³");
        System.out.println("You will need " + bNeeded + " balloons to fill the room.");
        return bNeeded;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help <3